# How to Get the Value of HTML5 date element in c# Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, html

I am using **C# Asp.Net** for creating a website. I have created an HTML5 date element in the web page. The date element is along with many other **.Net** elements (i.e textbox). I am unable to retrieve the value of date element.Below is my code

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox10" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<input type="date" id="myDate" name="sel_date" value="YY-MM-DD" />
```

I have tried tried many methods from stackoverflow but nothing worked. **i.e**

```
   1- String.Format("{0}", Request.QueryString["sel_date"]); // Not Working <br>
   2- myDate.Value; <br><br>
```

I can get the value of **textbox** as its a **.Net** element but how can I get the value of **Html5 Date element ?**.

Comment: You will never get the value of HTML control directly in code behind. Use JavaScript or asp.net tag runat="server" that convert the control to .net control.

Comment: @Janty - `You will never get the value of HTML control directly in code behind` isn't true...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code in **.Aspx file**

```
<input type="date" runat="server" id="myDate" name="sel_date" value="YY-MM-DD" />
```

and Access the value like this in .Aspx.cs file

```
String DOB = myDate.Value;
```

Comment: Compilation error `'date' is not a valid type for an input tag`

Answer (score 0):

> You will never get the value of HTML control directly in code behind.

Just a clarification to the above statement before it becomes "truth" :)

Yes, you **can** get **any/all** `input` field values, whether they are "server side control" or not (plain HTML `<input />`), from "code behind".

There is nothing wrong with this plain HTML5 `<input />` field, it *doesn't* have to be a "server side" control:

```
<input type="date" id="myDate" name="sel_date" value="YY-MM-DD" />
```

It will be in the [`Request.Form` collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525985(v=vs.90).aspx) on `POST`back:

- `Request.Form["sel_date"];`
- `Request["sel_date"];`

The original code "didn't work" because it was looking for it in [`Request.QueryString["sel_date"]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524784(v=vs.90).aspx)

Hth....